# How to convert json to google chart data?

Tags: json, ajax, linq, model-view-controller, google-visualization

I have a function which returns json in a controller of my MVC web app

```
public ActionResult GetWeeklyStats()
{
     using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
     {
          var result = db.sp_StoredProcedureName.ToList();
          return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
}
```

The returned data look like this:

```
   [
       {
          "WeekNo" : 1,
          "Count" : 230
       },
       {
          "WeekNo" : 2,
          "Count" : 240
       },
       {
          "WeekNo" : 3,
          "Count" : 250
       },
       {
          "WeekNo" : 4,
          "Count" : 260
       }
  ];
```

I am trying to set my google chart data in my view. Here is the ajax call in my view:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetWeeklyStats", "myControllerName")',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //set google data here ......
            //how to do it here???
        }
    });
```

The google data should look like this:

```
// Create the data table.
var gcData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
gcData.addColumn('number', 'WeekNo');
gcData.addColumn('number', 'Count');
gcData.addRows([
    [1, 230],
    [2, 240],
    [3, 250], 
    [4, 260]
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use can use the `addRow` method to add the values of each object in the data

see following snippet...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetWeeklyStats", "myControllerName")',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        // Create the data table.
        var gcData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        gcData.addColumn('number', 'WeekNo');
        gcData.addColumn('number', 'Count');

        $.each(data, function(i, row) {
            gcData.addRow([
                row.WeekNo,
                row.Count
            ]);
        });
    }
});
```